# Error al iniciar tensorboard de tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Estoy intentando iniciar el tensorboard de tensorflow. Esto en base a un modelo simple. Pero al ejecutar

```
 tensorboard --logdir output/
```

Me sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen se puede observar que dice que tf.estimator no esta instalado, pero ya revise esa parte, y si esta instalado correctamente.

He googleado bastante pero no he podido resolver este inconveniente 
Tengo la version de tensorflow 1.12 (Que es la mas actualizada).
Como podría solucionar este problema?.

De antemano gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambie de python 2.7 a 3.5 e inicie tensorboard (desde la version 3.5) y soluciono el problema.